# Converting mp3 to ogg, suggestions?

Tags: conversion, mp3, ogg, lame

I'm thinking about converting my mp3 based music library to ogg, due to ogg being a free and open standard format (I guess there are other reasons too). As far as I know there's a chance of losing some sound quality when converting mp3 to ogg and vice versa (?).

- Would you suggest converting mp3 to ogg, or is it such a bad idea that I'd have to rip all CDs to ogg instead of converting? (if this would turn up I'd rip to flac anyway I guess).
- How would I be able to convert mp3 to ogg the easiest way, copying ID3-Tags too? (on a *nix-based environment)

Best regards!

Comment: Rip to flac on one of the big hard drives we should all have these days, and use that as your master copy for MP3 players and stuff. It'll be worth it in the long run.

Comment: related: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/05/16/mp3_dies_nobody_noticed/

Comment: this should be on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MP3 is a lossy format. Ogg Vorbis is a lossy format. Therefore you will get the best results by re-ripping the CDs (non-lossy format).

Not familiar with Ogg tagging, but there is this:
http://easytag.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you *insist* on transcoding your audio files then [SoundConverter](http://soundconverter.berlios.de/) will bring the tags along as well.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for converting my entire mp3 collection to ogg a few years ago

```
find /home/shared/music -name *.mp3 -exec ogg2mp3 --delete {} \;
```

Left it overnight and in the morning I had an ogg collection.

It apparently resulted in lower quality, but I personally don't think it is is noticeable.

[ogg2mp3](http://faceprint.com/code/) is available in most Linux distributions repositories.

It is "A perl script to convert MP3 files to Ogg Vorbis files, retaining ID3 information..."